# How to clear root catalog products from sql (magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, category-products

I cleared all data but not able to clear root catalog products. These products are not available in product section. But still they are listed in root catalog  > categories Products section .

Any idea how to clear these products.

1) I already re-indexed and
2) flushed cache also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those category you are seeing this product delete from the database.

just replace with your category_id

```
delete from catalog_category_product where category_id = [Your_CATEGORY_Id];

delete from catalog_category_product_index where category_id = [Your_CATEGORY_Id];
```

Comment: i applied this sql all products are cleared , but after some time again there are products in that list with id and sku only.  <br> if run SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity`  i got a large list in databse havaing sku . what to do can i truncate this columns too

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan Idont know what is the issue may be some script that creates those product please check that way

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir . can i truncate sku column in database directly .

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan I dont advice you to directly instead create a script and load by sku and check and then delete programatically

Comment: sir are you talking about this type of script 
$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product','attr_code');

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan load all product by sku and check if product exists and if that product exists then delete it